# Workaround solution to avoid getters in Golang interface

Tags: go, interface, repository, getter

Thank you for taking some time to read this question!

I'm new to Golang and I've been developing a simple social media API to practice the language in general. In this project I'm using a struct to represent the Model of a Post published by an user, as follows:

```
// models/post.go

package models

import "time"

type Post struct {
    ID        uint64 
    Title     string    
    Content   string  
    AuthorID  uint64    
    Likes     uint64   
    CreatedAt time.Time
}

func (p *Post) ValidateFields() error {
    // validate fields
}
```

This post can be saved to the database with the help of a method that is inside a repository:

```
// repositories/posts.go

import (
    "database/sql"
    "models"
)

type PostsRepository struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func NewPostsRepository(db *sql.DB) *PostsRepository {
    return &PostsRepository{db}
}

func (r *PostsRepository) Save(models.Post) (uint64, error) { 
    // Passing the model as a parameter
}
```

As you can see, the model is being passed as a parameter and that feels like a problem for two reasons:

1. I only need three fields to save the post to database (Title,
   Content and AuthorID) because everything else will be generated
   automatically
2. If I write an unit test to the Save function it will
   rely on the model to work, therefore any problems with the model
   would impact the test

So with that in mind I thought about changing the parameter from a model to an interface, but since interfaces only accept method signatures and in that specific case I only need attributes to save data on the database, I assume it would need a few getters such as:

```
type PostInterface interface {
    GetTitle() string
    GetContent() string
    GetAuthorID() uint64
}
```

**(I know it is not idiomatic to call a getter "GetAttribute", but it's just to give you an idea)**

Due to that, I'd have to implement these three methods on my Post Model, which would look like

```
func (p Post) GetTitle() string {
    return p.Title
}

func (p Post) GetContent() string {
    return p.Content
}

func (p Post) GetAuthorID() uint64 {
    return p.AuthorID
}
```

That doesn't look so good, but it gets worse when we go to the test.
Like I said, I do not want to use the model in the test so I would have to create a struct to serve as a stub or something that has only the three needed fields for the Save to work (which sounds good). However, I'd have to implement these three methods again so that the struct can be accepted as an interface by the Save function (which sounds bad)

It sounds like a lot of unecessary work, Is there any way to work around this? I'm not sure if I'm missing something conceptual about Go or if there are any changes on my architecture that could address to this issue, but I'm having trouble finding alternatives to this

Thank you!

Comment: I do not see a problem in 1. and absolutely none in 2.

Comment: @Volker Not even if in the future the struct grows to be much larger than just the fields I'm currently using? I got concerned with this because in other languages I programmed in, it is a good practice to use only the things that you actually need to make functions work in general

Comment: Anticipating a future that might or might not come to existence is a bit futile and as you stated: _other_ languages and assume you have an algorithm on a graph which computes some statistics but does not use let's say the edges. Would you consider it "good practices" to write that function taking only the nodes as input and rewrite your graph data structure to a edge list just because you have a function which doesn't need the nodes? Of course not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a struct in the save function is perfectly fine and considered idiomatic. If this is just a data container I don't see any issues in testing this functionality. You could however opt for a slimmer version of the struct with just the respective fields you require when storing the content in the database.

For instance:

```
type Content struct {
    Title    string
    Content  string
    AuthorID uint64
}
```

If you still want to decouple with an interface you can create a method on the `Post` model and return the Content struct, personally I don't see the need for this since it will not improve the testability and only increases complexity by using another layer of abstraction.

In your tests you can just create an instance of the `Content struct` and pass that to the `Save` function.